# Database lock not working as expected with Rails & Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, transactions, locking

I have the following code in a rails model:

```
foo = Food.find(...)
foo.with_lock do
  if bar = foo.bars.find_by_stuff(stuff)
    # do something with bar
  else
    bar = foo.bars.create!
    # do something with bar
  end
end
```

The goal is to make sure that a Bar of the type being created is not being created twice.

Testing with_lock works at the console confirms my expectations. However, in production, it seems that in either some or all cases the lock is not working as expected, and the redundant Bar is being attempted -- so, the with_lock doesn't (always?) result in the code waiting for its turn.

What could be happening here?

**update**
so sorry to everyone who was saying "locking foo won't help you"!! my example initially didin't have the bar lookup. this is fixed now.

Comment: Where do you check whether a bar already exists?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Why would you bother checking? Any check outside the database will **always** have holes and race conditions.

Comment: I personally wouldn't but it might be helpful to the OP to work  out which bit of their understanding is flawed.

Comment: @FrederickCheung code example was bad before.. fixed now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason why a lock wouldn't be working in a Rails app in query cache.

If you try to obtain an exclusive lock on the same row multiple times in a single request, query cached kicks in so subsequent locking queries never reach the DB itself.

[The issue has been reported](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/867) on Github.

Answer (score 7):

You're confused about what `with_lock` does. From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-with_lock):

> **with_lock(lock = true)**
>
> Wraps the passed block in a transaction, locking the object before yielding. You pass can the SQL locking clause as argument (see `lock!`).

If you check what `with_lock` does internally, you'll see that it is little more than a thin wrapper around [`lock!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-lock-21):

> **lock!(lock = true)**
>
> Obtain a row lock on this record. Reloads the record to obtain the requested lock.

So `with_lock` is simply doing a row lock and locking `foo`'s row.

Don't bother with all this locking nonsense. The only sane way to handle this sort of situation is to use a unique constraint in the database, no one but the database can ensure uniqueness unless you want to do absurd things like locking whole tables; then just go ahead and blindly try your INSERT or UPDATE and trap and ignore the exception that will be raised when the unique constraint is violated.

Comment: I know my use of lock on `foo` was a bit of a hack, and your suggestion to handle the uniqueness constraint error is well taken (and indeed what I've ended up doing) -- but I would still like to know why this hacky code isn't working. it has the behavior I desire, which I've confirmed at the console and tests in my dev environment. While waiting for the lock on `foo` one process will wait for the other process. I've never had any timeout or deadlock errors from this code, which is a side effect I might fear from poorly designing it.

Comment: @JohnBachir: What do you think `foo.with_lock` does and why do you think it should solve your problem?

Comment: @muistooshort I can't agree more with the statement, "Don't bother with all this locking nonsense". Your suggestion works perfectly for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to handle this situation is actually right in the Rails docs:

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

```
begin
  CreditAccount.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

("find_or_create_by" is not atomic, its actually a find and then a create. So replace that with your find and then create. The docs on this page describe this case exactly.)

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a unique constraint? It's made for uniqueness

Comment: i do have a uniquness constraint in place, and it does its job. sometimes one of the concurrent saves fails. so, no redundant data is created, but the code blows up instead of waiting for its turn.

Comment: You don't need a table lock for error handling, it makes your application extremely slow. RoR must have something better, but I can't help you there.

Comment: @JohnBachir: It blows up because you're not catching and handling the exception that is raised when the unique constraint is violated. You **must** trap and handle those exception, there is nothing sane you can do in Rails to prevent them. The only sane strategy with these sorts of things is to let the database deal with it, your code should simply try it and deal with the expected exceptions and failures.

Comment: @muistooshort there should never be a uniqueness constraint violation, because my code is only allowed to create or fetch one bar at a time per foo (not a great design, but should work nonetheless)

Comment: @JohnBachir: But how do you expect locking a `foo` row will stop you from creating a `bar`?

Comment: process 1 locks foo, then process 2 tries to acquire the lock and has to wait for the lock to be released before proceeding. in the meantime, process 1 creates the bar and releases the lock. now process 2 moves forward, looks for the bar, and finds it, and does not try to create another one.

Comment: holy crap, i just realized my example doesn't include the Bar lookup. SO SORRY!!! fixing now...

Comment: @JohnBachir: The `Bar` lookup has nothing at all to do with the row lock on `foo` inside the database, your thinking a couple comments back is flawed.

Comment: @muistooshort you are correct, locking the foo doesn't affect bar in the database, however it does affect the concurrency behavior of the ruby code. it's a (mis)use of database locks as a ruby mutex. after monkeypatching rails for the bug described in the answer, the behavior became what i expected.